# Node Express. Is there a way to send more complex data to the serverside with a form?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Is there a way to send more information to the server side (for example an object)?

By creating a form and adding an input

```
<form action="/home" method="POST">
    <input name="title">
    <input name="content">
</form>
```

we get

```
{
   title: "a",
   content: "something"
}
```

Is there a way to do something like that:

```
{
   title: "a",
   content: {
               something: "f"
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When submitting a form, you’re actually sending over a [formdata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object, and no, it doesn’t support `json` format.

Comment: then how can I store and send this type of data?

Comment: I’d suggest flatten the data. contentSomething1, contentSomething2…etc. Another way is to use REST based api.